# Selenium C#: How to check/assert copied text? (Net6)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

On my website, I can click on a button, which does copy text. In the screenshot below this is how it looks like:

[image]

After clicking on the copy text, it should copy the text `Bitte einschalten und ausschalten äüöß 876543212345678` which can be seen on the bottom of the picture.

Now I would like to check, if the copy function worked and if the text on the webpage, is the same as the one which has been copied.

I was already searching for answers, but nothing worked for me.

My idea was to paste the text into the browser's URL field and then compare it, but it seems that selenium is not able to access this URL field.

There is also no other text field where I could paste the text inside.

Would appreciate any help!

EDIT: There was a method in C# which doesnt work in .NET Core anymore.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Looking for a other solution like this.

Comment: but it seems that selenium is not able to access this url field. - Update the question with the code that you've tried?

Comment: @cruisepandey i only know the GoToUrl(url) method from selenium. But this opens the pasted string directly.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of JavaScript, you might be able to do this:

1. Create a text field using JavaScript.
2. Get the value of the text field.

```
var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var textareaId = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();

var script = $@"
var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
textarea.id = '{textareaId}';
document.body.appendChild(textarea);";

js.ExecuteScript(script);

var textarea = driver.FindElement(By.Id(textareaId));

// Paste clipboard into textarea
textarea.SendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "v");

var clipboardText = textarea.GetProperty("value");
```

Just be aware of where this text area gets appends to the page. If it is hidden or partially obstructed by another element, you will get an `ElementNotInteractableException`. If this happens, pick a different element on the page when appending the textarea. Just replace `document.body.appendChild(textarea)` with a reference to a different element.

For example: `document.getElementById('someOtherElementId').appendChild(textarea)`